# Show that the quotient ring $R/\mathcal{I}$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

1) Let $R$ be a ring with a maximal ideal $\mathcal{I}$. Show that the quotient ring $R/\mathcal{I}$ is a field.
Previously, I proved that

> $*$ Let $R$ be a ring. $R$ is a field if and
>   only if the only ideals of $R$ are $\{0\}$ and $R$.

I saw online that the prove of (1)  that states

> there is an obvious correspondence between the ideals of
>   $R/\mathcal{I}$ and ideals of $R$ that contain $\mathcal{I}$. The
>   result therefore follows immediately from $*$.

How is this possible?

Comment: How is *what* possible?

Comment: How does the second quoted result prove (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi \colon R \to R/I$ be the canonical projection map. Here are some facts you can use to prove the quoted result.

1) For any ideal $J$ of $R/I$, $\pi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of $R$.

2) Every ideal of a ring contains $0$, so in particular, every $0+I \in J$ for every ideal $J$ of $R/I$.

3) If $J, K \subseteq R/I$ are ideals such that $J$ is a proper subset of $K$, then $\pi^{-1}(J)$ is a proper subset of $\pi^{-1}(K)$.

Note that (1)+(2) imply that for any ideal $J$ in $R/I$, $I = \pi^{-1}(0+I) \subseteq \pi^{-1}(J)$. Certainly, $\langle 0 + I \rangle$ and $R/I$ are two ideals of $R/I$. Suppose there were any ideal $J$ of $R/I$ such that $\langle 0 + I \rangle \subset J \subset R/I$ with both inclusions proper. Then $I = \pi^{-1}(\langle 0 + I \rangle) \subset \pi^{-1}(J) \subset \pi^{-1}(R/I) = R$, which contradicts the fact that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Hence, the only two ideals of $R/I$ are $\{0\}$ and $R/I$.

More generally, one can in fact very slightly modify the above to show that there is a bijective correspondence between ideals of $R/I$ and ideals of $R$ which contain $I$. (1)+(2)+(3) show that the correspondence $J \mapsto \pi^{-1}(J)$ as a map between ideals of $R/I$ and ideals of $R$ which contain $I$ is injective and makes sense, and surjectivity is straightforward to show as well.

Comment: I am with you about having a canonical projection map, and I have proven, previously, fact (1). Of course an ideal of a ring have the $0$ element because it is a normal subgroup under addition. Where I am following is the last part. how do I know $I \in J$?

Comment: You don't know $I \subseteq J$; that doesn't really make sense, since $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $J$ is an ideal of $R/I$. You know that $\pi^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of $R$, and $0 \in J$, so $\pi^{-1}(0) = \ker(\pi) \subseteq \pi^{-1}(J)$. What is $\ker(\pi)$?

Comment: Isn't $ker(\pi)=0$ since the $0$ element of $R$ needs to map to the $0$ element of $R/I$?

Comment: Certainly, $0 \in \ker(\pi)$, but $\ker(\pi) = I$.

Comment: I am completely with you. So with these three facts I have shown that $R/\mathcal{I}$ has an invertible element, which is the only thing I need to show that it is a field. Am I correct?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: Well, you need to show that *every* element of $R/I$ is invertible, so if you've done that, then that's correct. My hints were intended to provide a proof of the statement you posted - I'll update my answer with what I had in mind.

Comment: I never thought of proving that $R/\mathcal{I}$ is a field that way. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: glad I could help!